# How do I make Google Chrome stop looking for a manifest that does not exist?

Tags: google-chrome, console, manifest.json

I usually open my Chrome console to check if there are any errors with whatever JavaScript code I use on my website, and I like it clean so I can immediately see what the errors are. However, I had to open the *Application* tab today to see something in the *Local Storage* subsection, and I accidentally clicked on *Manifest* which was near it.

Now the console is showing four errors that are different variations of this one, which I guess is normal since my website does not have any manifest whatsoever attached to it:

`Access to manifest at '[LINK TO PAGE]' from origin '[MY DOMAIN]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

But the problem is that these errors are not going away, even after I close the browser and reopen it. What's going on? How do I clear my console again, and make Chrome stop looking for a manifest that's not there?